# Sending SqlDataReader to constructor as parameter and constructor argument error

Tags: c#, constructor, sqldatareader

I created a public class and wrote a public constructor with parameters like:

```
public Patient(SqlDataReader reader, string p) {
        if (p == "L") {
            Name = reader[0].ToString();
        }
        else { }
    }
```

then I used this constructor like

```
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Patient myP(reader, "L");                    
                }
```

Then during debug, I got the error: Error  49  Expected ; or = (cannot specify constructor arguments in declaration)

Where is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: I should say: you might find it more effective to use tools like ORMs or micro-ORMs to populate the objects; the "use a data-reader to fill an object" is pretty-much a solved problem

Answer (score 5):

That syntax simply isn't valid; try:

```
Patient myP = new Patient(reader, "L");
```

or (identical result):

```
var myP = new Patient(reader, "L");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use constructor with `new` operator like;

```
Patient p = new Patient(reader, "L");
```

Your syntax is invalid for C#.

From [`new Operator (C# Reference)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa0ab757.aspx)

> Used to create objects and **invoke constructors**.